# How to group by week and distinct by day in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Sample contents are:

| id | created_dt | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-14 11:52:41 | {"customers": 1, "payments: 2} |
| 2 | 2023-01-15 11:53:43 | {"customers": 1, "payments: 2} |
| 3 | 2023-01-18 11:51:45 | {"customers": 1, "payments: 2} |
| 4 | 2023-01-15 11:50:48 | {"customers": 1, "payments: 2} |

ID 4 or 2 should be distinct.

I want to get a result as follows:

| year | week | customers | payments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| 2023 | 3 | 1 | 2 |

I solved this problem in this way

```sql
SELECT
    date_part('year', sq.created_dt) AS year,
    date_part('week', sq.created_dt) AS week,
    sum((sq.data->'customers')::int) AS customers,
    sum((sq.data->'payments')::int) AS payments
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT ON (created_dt::date) created_dt, data 
     FROM analytics) sq
GROUP BY 
    year, week
ORDER BY 
    year, week;
```

However, that subquery greatly complicates the query. Is there is a better method?

I need group the data by each week, however I also need to remove duplicate days.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Make it easy to help you.

Comment: Your subquery's DISTINCT ON will give you a random row per day. As intended?

Comment: @jarlh yep, this is fine

Comment: *Is there a better method?* Nope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think your query is quite simple and understandable.

Here is the query with a `with`-query in it, in some point it adds more readabilty:

```
WITH unique_days_data AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT created_dt::date, data_json
  FROM analytics)
SELECT 
    date_part('year', ud.created_dt) as year,
    date_part('week', ud.created_dt) as week,
    sum((ud.data_json->'customers')::int) as customers,
    sum((ud.data_json->'payments')::int) as payments
FROM unique_days_data ud
GROUP BY year, week
ORDER BY year, week;
```

The difference is that the first query uses the `DISTINCT` clause, not the `DISTINCT ON` clause.

Here is the [sql fiddle](https://onecompiler.com/postgresql/3yuvx6uhk).

Answer (score 0):

Generate series to create the join table would solve the problem :

```
SELECT sum((sq.data->'customers')::int) as customers,
sum((sq.data->'payments')::int) as payments,
date_part('year', dategroup ) as year,
date_part('week', dategroup ) as week,
FROM generate_series(current_date , current_date+interval '1 month' , interval'1 week') AS dategroup
JOIN analytics AS a ON a.created_dt >= dategroup AND a.created_dt <= a.created_dt+interval '1 week'
GROUP BY dategroup
ORDER BY dategroup
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it by adding partitioning on "*created_id::date*", then filter last aggregated record for each week using `FETCH FIRST n ROWS WITH TIES`.

```
SELECT date_part('year', created_dt) AS year,
       date_part('week', created_dt) AS week,
       SUM((data->>'customers')::int) AS customers,
       SUM((data->>'payments')::int) AS payments
FROM analytics
GROUP BY year, week, created_dt::date
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
             PARTITION BY date_part('week', created_dt) 
             ORDER     BY created_dt::date DESC
         )
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2Aqsafk25TWrd8Zd4kuvWw/0).